# Does always exist a CW-decomposition of topological space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Does always exist a CW-decomposition of topological space ?

Comment: SImple answer: no.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. The Cantor set doesn't have a CW-decomposition. It this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1081/what-is-an-example-of-a-topological-space-that-is-not-homotopy-equivalent-to-a-c) they have another examples.

Comment: If the answer is correct for you, you can click on the tick of the quetion to make it valid